# Jelastic configure firewall

Tags: iptables, jelastic

I'm using [Jelastic](https://jelastic.com/) for my application and I just installed the Apache for it. The problem is that I need to set up a firewall for it, like iptables or other, after all is a web application and it needs security.

How can I do that?

The host said to me, that the only way is to use VDS and I should configure a VDS for me, installing Apache, FTP and transfer my application to there.

But I can believe that there is no way to protect the Apache.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The available options vary depending on your hosting provider. For example, the Jelastic platform gives hosting providers and private cloud customers the ability to define a set of default firewall rules for each newly provisioned node.

Additionally, since Jelastic 4.1, there is an option for the provider to define additional custom firewall rules for any specific container. At the moment this functionality is only accessible from the provider's side, so it means you need to work with your provider's support team.

If you don't want to do that, or your chosen Jelastic provider does not offer good support, you can either:

1. Use an unmanaged node type in your Jelastic environments, such as the Elastic VPS or Docker nodes. Here you have full root access to define whatever firewall rules you desire.
2. Use application server rules to restrict access according to IP. E.g. inside your httpd.conf (which you already have full access to customise)

Answer (score 0):

In the recent release, Jelastic introduced a possibility to manage inbound and outbound firewall rules on the container level right through the interface. The detailed [instruction is here](https://jelastic.com/blog/container-firewall-rules-management-interface-for-inbound-outbound-traffic-control/).