# AWS-like security groups and networking in Jelastic

Tags: networking, jelastic

I'm looking for AWS-like security groups in Jelastic platform. 
In AWS all the things are pretty straightforward: you create vpc, define subnets, define in/out rules and that's it.
There's options to set public/private IPs for the boxes, get the runtime information using API or cloudformation and many other useful things.

Is there something like this in Jelastic platform? I've lurked through UI but didn't found anything except of endpoints which allows me to open some node for the world.

Comment: It is possible to configure [custom firewall rules](https://docs.jelastic.com/setting-custom-firewall). [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701849/jelastic-configure-firewall) can be helpful as well. Also there are [API](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/), [CLI](https://docs.jelastic.com/cli) and [JPS](https://github.com/jelastic-jps) that help to automate complex workflows. In addition, there is an option to setup a fully isolated and dedicated cloud region only for your app which is good for a big project. Could you describe your use case/specific needs in details?

Comment: @Ruslan: imagine I have micro-services application. I want to restrict access to nodes by IP without iptables and other manual sysop-like stuff. In AWS I could do this in several clicks. Also I'd like to setup proper networking with isolated hosts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my perspective few options are possible now:

1) New version of Jelastic has an ability to use isolated networks per each environment, but this version is not in production yet. You can wait until this version will be available in production, but I don't think that option can be good for you as the biggest waste in our life is a waste of time.

2) Write a simple JPS addon that automatically apply custom firewall rule set per each container in your environment. Such an addon can be written once and then can be applied to all your environments in future. Actually CloudScripting way helps to make automation of any level (including infrastructure behaviour / events subscription / deployments and etc.) In that way any topology modifications can be aumaticaly reflected in firewall rules and applied.

3) Manual firewall configuration using this article
[Manual Firewall configuration in Jelastic](https://docs.jelastic.com/setting-custom-firewall)
Probably can be the fastest solution, but it depends. If you have let's say 5 containers - that is fine as a temporary solution until more advanced feature will be available. If you have 100 containers - it's easier to write an addon. There are many examples available on [Github JPS](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/)

Comment: When the next release will be GA and deployed to major providers?